# debug jest with source-map support

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, babeljs

I'm using `jest` with `babel` and i want to debug my test.
I'm able to debug jest with `node --debug-brk ./node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand [any other arguments here]` but lose all es6 source code info.
I know `source-map-support` is  a `babel` feature not `jest's`, but `jest` should somehow tell `babel` to include `source-map-support`.

so far I've tried

1. config `transform` for `jest`

```
    "transform": {
           ".*": "/scripts/jest/preprocessor.js"
    }
```

2. in my preprocess.js file I have

```
    const register=require("babel-register")
    register();
    ....

    module.exports = {
        process: function(src, filename) {
            const options = assign({}, babelOptions, {
              filename: filename,
              retainLines: true,
             sourceMap:true,    // I added this line
            });
            return babel.transform(src, options).code;
    }
```

but this doesn't work. any ideas?